# cli utility crashing while invoked using popen in c++. Works fine in shell or fork, exec etc

Tags: c++, linux

I am facing a weird problem. I have written a command line utility which calls a third party library apis to do some management tasks of the third party appliance. I have throughly tested the utility and it works fine. I have my own daemon (written in c++), which based on the request it receives, calls this command line utility using popen. If I do this, the utility crashes in the library api, giving error which looks like this

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

my cli utility is invoked like this

```
./cli --host hostname --command cmd --other otheropts etc etc.
```

it is invoked from the daemon using c++ string, where daemon builds the arguments based on the request it got. It finally calls my cli like this

```
setenv("LOGIN", login_.c_str(), 1);
setenv("PASSWORD", password_.c_str(), 1);
std::string complete = cli_path_ + " ";
complete += formatString("--host %s --command ", host_);
complete += cmd;
complete += " 2>&1"; // get stderr as well

FILE *f = popen(complete.c_str(), "r");
```

Then reads the resulting file pointer and parses the output. 
The crash happens only while calling from the daemon, not from the shell. Even if I invoke a wrapper shell script from the daemon, it still crashes. I am not understanding the relationship of the execed process with its parent, where it can cause the crash. I understand that somewhere the api is trying to create a string out of a null pointer, however, what baffles me is, it does not happen when I invoke the cli directly from command line or from a simple c++ program I wrote to invoke it. The OS is linux.
To debug, I have tried

1. invoking it using fork and exec instead of popen. (crashes)
2. invoke a shell script which invokes this cli. (crashes)
3. invoke directly like shown above. (works)
4. invoke from shell using a c++ simple program as wrapper (works)
5. Step in gdb till the third party api. (crashes in the api when invoked from daemon)

Comment: My bad, actually its a wrapper, which returns the string which is result of formatting the given input. I will change the name to something else.

Comment: "Returns the resultant string pointer" *how*? Returning a pointer to a local variable? Is it the "cli" program that throws an exception, or the program forming the command and calling `popen`?

Comment: And have you changed the name of the function in your actual code as well? Because otherwise who knows what overload the compiler will choose? The standard `sprintf` function takes at least two pointers to strings, which just happens to be the arguments you pass to your formatting function.

Comment: its a wrapper that returns a malloced string. The name is not sprintf in the source, I just changed it to sprintf while posting the question, since functionality is similar to sprintf in a sense. I have verified that all the arguments are properly coming to cli utility. If it was returning a pointer to local variable, I would not need to post the question here, it would always crash, not just when called from my daemon. The crash is happening in the third party api, that my cli utility calls. So to answer your second question, its crash from the command that is being called from popen

Comment: Then you have a memory leak instead instead of UB. :) The UB is in the third-part application you call, and might not be something you really can do anything about if you can't debug it.

Comment: The problem I am concerned is not debugging memory leak or third party api, my question is why the crash is happening when called from daemon and not from cli. if there was a problem in api, it should have crashed even from cli. since exec happens in a different address space, why is it crashing only when called from my daemon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111735/discussion-between-manish-and-joachim-pileborg).

Comment: One of the symptoms of UB is that sometimes it might seem to work, unfortunately. There's simply no way to say why the third-party program throws an exception when you run it one way, but not another. Not without actually debug it and understand what the root problem is. If the third-part program really is third-part, and nothing you have access to source or can debug in other ways, there's no way to solve or even understand what's wrong with it. One tiny possible way to try and figure it out is to make sure the string you pass to `popen` is *exactly* the same you use from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. The third party library was trying to access a environment variable which was not defined. The library code did not handle this and crashed. So problem was in the third party library, which they have agreed to fix. 
Just for the benefit of others, I discovered this by doing a lot of debugging as mentioned above. Finally I was suspicious about the environment. So I ran the cli with "env -i" like this,

```
env -i ./cli --args <args>
```

which clears the environment variables. It crashed!. Then I figured out which environment variable by doing a binary search on all the environment variables that were set while running the cli.